# Анимация смена цвета кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-animation

У меня есть кнопка и мне нужно чтобы цвет кнопки менялся при нажатии, например был белый цвет стал зеленый, желательно через **Анимацию**.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="2"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="200"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" />

</set>
```

onClick

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;
        Drawable background = v.getBackground();

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);

        if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonNext) {
            createActivity();

            // Осторожно эта для 300IQ муверов.
            return;

        } else {
            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("OLEG", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM summary WHERE id = " + realAnswerID +";", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            if(cursor.getString(2).equals(button.getText())) {
                anim.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                db.execSQL("UPDATE summary SET progress_rating = " +
                        (cursor.getInt(3) + 2) +
                        " WHERE id = '"+ realAnswerID + "';");

            } else {
                anim.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                db.execSQL("UPDATE summary SET progress_rating = "
                        + (cursor.getInt(3) - 1) +
                        " WHERE id = '" + realAnswerID + "';");

            }
        }

        // Не рельные АНИМАЦИИ из ИНТЕРНЕТА
        v.startAnimation(anim);

        v.setBackground(background);

        createActivity();
    }
```

Я пытался но не работает смена цвета.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала сделаем drawable файл с цветами и состояниями:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnorm" />
</selector>
```

применим к кнопке данный фон в xml:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/mybutton"
  android:background="@drawable/watever" />
```

Теперь по поводу анимации. Есть такой вариант:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/original_state" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_state" />
</transition>
```

и дальше в активности применяем к кнопке:

```
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) viewObj.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(transitionTime);
```

где viewObj это ваша кнопка. Вот есть подобные вопросы [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-on-android) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked)